# Upgrading react native from 0.36.x to 0.47.1 | SyntaxError const { root, ...args } = allArgs;

Tags: javascript, react-native, syntax-error, upgrade

React native project upgraded from `0.36.0` to `0.47.1` and resolved all the conflicts and upgraded other third-party modules too when trying to run the command `react-native run-android` it gives the following the issue. But this `/Project_path/ProjectNamenode_modules/react-native/local-cli/server/server.js` file created from the current react native repository **(v 0.47.1 )**. I replaced this file with an older version file and then an android device only shows a blank screen and crash after build success. Any suggestion?

```
/Project_path/ProjectNamenode_modules/react-native/local-cli/server/server.js:25
  const { root, ...args } = allArgs;
                ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:533:28)
    at loader (/Project_path/ProjectName/node_modules/metro-bundler/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Project_path/ProjectName/node_modules/metro-bundler/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

Comment: You need to use `transform-object-rest-spread` https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/

Comment: @Dan, You solved my issue, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with 0.48.0 ... after removing node module, clean node cache and reinstall 0.47.1 it was ok.

If you have declare your dependancy in package.json `"react-native": "^0.47.1"` you got the 0.48

You must declare `"react-native": "0.47.1"`